# Tzitzis Niputz Lishma -ניפוץ לשמה , are there different levels?

Tags: halacha, tzitzis, mishnah-berurah, stringency-chumrah

The משנה [ברורה סימן יא ס"ק](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.11.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) ג brings the opinion of the מהר"ל מפראג to be machmir on the subject of Niputz lishma in Tzitzis. In other words, already from the point of spinning the wool, should it be done with having the Tzitzis in mind.

When selecting such Tzitzis (strings only, not including the begged) in judaica stores many price ranges are offered, sometimes from as low as approx. $30 up to approx. $70 for seemingly similar products.

Are there different stringencies involved in how to aquire a Niputz Lishma level that are the reason for the different price ranges? Any other reason?

Comment: From my experience, the price differences are for other things like 2 holes, size etc

Comment: @Chatzkel I was referring to pricing of strings only. I clarified the question

Comment: There’s machine lishma (using koach kocho) there’s how it’s cut, from when the lishma started, amongst countless other variations of chumros. And of course, think vs thin, and the hechsher….

Comment: As a general rule, sellers will advertise anything they can. If they had niputz lishma, they would definitely let you know.